# ESA build Expo managed Android App not displaying map in APK

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, google-maps, expo, native

I have a learning project build with expo manaed react native app. It has Google Map display in home screen.
My Android app is fine when running on expo go, but it is not showing Google map in APK. It only shows the grayish background and Google icon at bottom left.

My app backend is managed as Firebase project. Map service is Google Map service.

eas.json code here :

```json
{
  "build": {
    "preview": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "preview2": {
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
      }
    },
    "preview3": {
      "developmentClient": true
    },
    "preview4": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

my app.json code :

```json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "TestApp",
    "slug": "TestApp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.yourcompany.TestApp",
      "config": {
        "googleMaps": {
          "apiKey": "@env:GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY"
        }
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "122334456677788"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried solving this issue by following older Stack Overflow articles, but app is not working.

Comment: This could be related to your credentials (API Key or SHA-1), I'd suggest you file a support case so that a support agent can take a look inside your project and see what might have gone wrong. https://developers.google.com/maps/support#contact-maps-support